# How do I pass the <div> element (to get its id) from CKEditor-->uploads()-->_initRequest()?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have 2 CKEditor fields () in the View.

```
<div id="editor_1">
     @Html.Raw(@Model.Description_1)
</div>

<div id="editor_2">
     @Html.Raw(@Model.Description_2)
</div>
```

There is a code that transmits the uploaded image to the controller:

```
<script>

class MyUploadAdapter {
    
    upload() {
        return this.loader.file
            .then( file => new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
                this._initRequest();
                this._initListeners( resolve, reject, file );
                this._sendRequest( file );
            } ) );
    }

    _initRequest() {
        const xhr = this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
}

</script>
```

How do I pass in _initRequest() a link to the elements  and  to understand which field the user is uploading the image to (I need to get the field id)? I tried to figure it out in the controller (in Request class) where I receive the uploaded image, but I couldn't.

foreach (IFormFile photo in Request.Form.Files)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom upload adapter to send files to the backend as part of the request. When creating an instance of the adapter, you can get the id of the current element through `editor.sourceElement.getAttribute('id')`.

Then, create a new XMLHttpRequest and add the element id to the request headerFinally, it is sent to the backend via HTTP request headers.
On the backend, a method is used to obtain the corresponding id from the request header.
Here is an example you can use as a reference:

```
@model Mymodel

<div class="tab-panels">

    <div id="editor_1"></div>
    @Html.Raw(Model?.Description_1)

    <div id="editor_2"></div>
    @Html.Raw(Model?.Description_2)
</div>


<script src=https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/41.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js></script>

<script>

    class MyUploadAdapter {
        constructor(loader, fieldId) {
            
            this.loader = loader;
            this.url = '/Upload/DocUploadImage';
            this.fieldId = fieldId;
        }

        // Starts the upload process.
        upload() {
            return this.loader.file
                .then(file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    this._initRequest();
                    this._initListeners(resolve, reject, file);
                    this._sendRequest(file);
                }));
        }

        // Aborts the upload process.
        abort() {
            if (this.xhr) {
                this.xhr.abort();
            }
        }
        _initRequest() {
            const xhr = this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', this.url, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-FieldId', this.fieldId);
            xhr.responseType = 'json';
           
        }

        _initListeners(resolve, reject, file) {
            const xhr = this.xhr;
            const loader = this.loader;
            const genericErrorText = `Couldn't upload file: ${file.name}.`;

            xhr.addEventListener('error', () => reject(genericErrorText));
            xhr.addEventListener('abort', () => reject());
            xhr.addEventListener('load', () => {
                const response = xhr.response;

                if (!response || response.error) {
                    return reject(response && response.error ? response.error.message : genericErrorText);
                }

                resolve({
                    default: response.url
                });
            });

            if (xhr.upload) {
                xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', evt => {
                    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                        loader.uploadTotal = evt.total;
                        loader.uploaded = evt.loaded;
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        // Prepares the data and sends the request.
        _sendRequest(file) {         
            const data = new FormData();
            data.append('upload', file);
            this.xhr.send(data);
        }
    }

    function MyCustomUploadAdapterPlugin(editor) {
        editor.plugins.get('FileRepository').createUploadAdapter = (loader) => {
            
            const fieldId = editor.sourceElement.getAttribute('id');
         
            return new MyUploadAdapter(loader, fieldId);
        };
    }

    ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector('#editor_1'), {
        extraPlugins: [MyCustomUploadAdapterPlugin]
    })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });

    ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector('#editor_2'), {
        extraPlugins: [MyCustomUploadAdapterPlugin]
    })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });


</script>
```

accept method:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> DocUploadImage()
{
    var fieldId = HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-FieldId"].ToString();


    return Json("OK");
}
```

When I send the image:
[image]

I can get the corresponding element id in the request header:

[image]
[image]

Comment: It probably works too. Thanks! I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by myself by getting the focus - in which field the image is uploaded. The issue is closed. https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/deep-dive/ui/focus-tracking.html